# Adding float to float results in nan

Tags: arduino, nan

Been having this issue that has got me very confused. I've got an Arduino on an e-bike to control speed and other things. Below is a part of that sketch that averages the readings from the bike speed. frontSpeedo is what is triggered via interrupt when bike wheel turns (but in below code it is in the loop instead, to simulate wheel turning). Then speedCalc calculates the speed and then uses the movingAverage function to get the average speed. I got the average function from this forum (from mr. lurker. Thanks by the way!) and use it here and there and it works. But in this instance it does not. I mean, the problem is not in the average function in it self, rather somewhere else in my code. The return of movingAverage is nan, a result of this `sum += value;`. I don't understand why, but here are some workarounds I stumbled upon trying to correct this:

1. In movingAverage, replace the float's with int's.
2. Change the delay in loop to anything bigger than 36.
3. Removing the debounce in frontSpeedo.

Unfortunately none of these workarounds are useable to me. Besides, I'm really curious as to what is causing this. I run this "simulation" on a Nano Every on the e-bike its a pro mini. I use the Arduino IDE 1.8.19.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

```
unsigned long frontElapsed = 0;
unsigned long frontLastElapsed = 0;
float avgKmh = 0;
float frontKmh = 0;
const int diameterMm = 2200;
const int magnetsPerWheel = 3;
const int distancePerInterrupt = diameterMm / magnetsPerWheel;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop(){
  delay(36);
  frontSpeedo();  
  speedCalc();
  Serial.print("frontKmh: ");
  Serial.println(frontKmh);
  Serial.print("avgKmh: ");
  Serial.println(avgKmh);
}

void frontSpeedo(){ //this runs at interrupt when bike wheel turns
  if ( 35 < (millis() - frontLastElapsed)){  //debounce
    frontElapsed = millis() - frontLastElapsed;
    frontLastElapsed = millis();
  }
}

void speedCalc(){
  if ( 1200 < (millis() - frontLastElapsed)){
    frontKmh = 0;
  }else{
    frontKmh = (3.6 * distancePerInterrupt) / frontElapsed;
    avgKmh = movingAverage(frontKmh);
  }
}

float movingAverage(float value) {
  const byte nvalues = 3;             // Moving average window size
  static byte current = 0;            // Index for current value
  static byte cvalues = 0;            // Count of values read (<= nvalues)
  static float sum = 0;               // Rolling sum
  static float values[nvalues];

  sum += value;

  // If the window is full, adjust the sum by deleting the oldest value
  if (cvalues == nvalues)
    sum -= values[current];

  values[current] = value;          // Replace the oldest with the latest

  if (++current >= nvalues)
    current = 0;

  if (cvalues < nvalues)
    cvalues += 1;

  return sum/cvalues;
}
```